# Screen CS:GO server cvar change

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

i want to send commands into a screen with .sh script.
Start a CSGO server with:
`screen -S cs ./srcds_run -game csgo -usercon`
How can i send a command to the csgo server like:
`sv_cheats 1`

Answer (score 0):

From the screen manpage:

> -X   Send the specified command to a running screen session.

At https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen you find a similar question.

So for your specific problem the solution would be:

```
screen -S cs -X stuff "sv_scheats 1"
```

Comment: so the line is now inside the server console but i need someone to press enter?

Comment: just add \n at the end

Comment: screen -S cs -p 0 -X stuff "sv_cheats 0"^M  that finaly worked